# ddclient Running Info

Tags: ddclient

`ddclient` seems powerful, however the only status message I can see is that it is running, by doing `sudo /etc/init.d/ddclient status`.

Is it possible to check what current ip is cached? since when? what's the time left until the next check? what's the host associated?

Just like No-IP client for Windows.

Answer (score 17):

I think what you're looking for is: `sudo ddclient -query`

That command will spit out the local IP addresses of all the interfaces on the machine (eg: lo, eth0, wlan0) followed by the dynamic public IP addresses current set for with dyndns.com.

Peace.

Answer (score 11):

You can also run the following command:

```
sudo ddclient -daemon=0 -debug -verbose -noquiet
```

This will provide the send, connected, and receive to show you a complete visual of the completed calls and it will provide a success or fail at the end.

Comment: ugh.  why is it talking to a bunch of server that are mentioned nowhere in /etc/dhclient.conf and NOT talking to the one server I *have* specified?!

Answer (score 3):

I added `verbose=yes` in `/etc/ddclient.conf` and information showed up in `/var/log/syslog`.

Answer (score 0):

The following command gives the status of all services:
"`service --status-all`"

Try also:
"`ps -ef`"
to know how long a service has been "sleeping." This will let you know when ddclient will attempt to update your IP address.